# C++: advanced function definition

Tags: c++, function, operator-keyword, definition

I just encountered several online examples.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

Split is calling the other split inside of it. Is this allowed? The two function have the same name, will C++ be able to pick which one to use based on the number of arguments?

Also, I'm trying to define how an object of class Event is represented with a string. This is a piece of code that works for me:

```
inline ostream & operator << (ostream & Str, Event const & event)
{
        //do stuff here    
        return Str;
}
```

besides inline, I do not understand how the declaration of this works.(&, operator, <<, etc...)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Teach me C++" is not a specific programming question. Read a tutorial.

Comment: To understand the first example look up function overloading, then when you understand that, look up operator overloading to understand the second bit.

Comment: Here is a start Google: 1) Function overloading 2) Conversion constructor.

Comment: poor newbie, our flurry of downvotes just robbed him of whatever modicum of rep he had left. :(

Comment: @greatwolf He could have avoided this by reading the FAQ before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) allows the use of multiple functions/methods with the same name but with a differing number argument or types thereof. Those functions are put into overload resolution and, depending on the types of the parameters passed to `split` (or the number of the parameters) the compiler will attempt choose the correct one when they are called.
2. `T& x` means `x` is a reference for what ever `T` object it is bound to. When a reference is used in a parameter list, it means that there is no copy/move-construction performed and that the object `x` is now an *alias* to its variable. Note that non-const references cannot be bound to temporaries (aka rvalues).

   For your other question, search for [Operator Overloading](https://www.google.com/search?q=operator%20overloading%20in%20c%2b%2b&oq=operator%20overloading%20in%20c%2b%2b&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j5j0j60j62.4360j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Why is ostream $Str passsed as an argument? Is that just how the << operator works?

Comment: @quannguyen This is a global operator overload. All global operators take 2 parameters, one of which must be of class type. The first parameter is an object of `std::ostream`. The `&` denotes a reference. In all, the first parameter type is `std::ostream&`. `Str` is simply the name of the parameter. You would use it like this: `std::cout << str` (where `evt` is an object of type `Event`).